# How to remove WMS layer from OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, wms

How to remove added WMS layer from OpenLayers?
I have seen a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12126067/removing-a-layer-in-openlayers), but I didn't get clearly.

I have added the WMS layer as follows:

```
<script src="../OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map, layer;
    function init(){
        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/worksapce/wms", {layers: 'basic'} );
        var layer_1=new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://localhost:8090/geoserver/worksapce/wms", 
                 {
                 layers:"states",
                 format:'image/png'
                 },
                 {isBaseLayer:false}
                 );
        map.addLayer([layer,layer_1);
        map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher() );
    }
</script>
```

This code is working fine and adding layer_1 as a overlay layer. Similarly I added 5 more over layers as above, now I want to remove layer_1 using OpenLayers code like `map.removeLayer(layer_1);`.

Please help me

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is one of Javascrip variable scope.

The variable layer_1 is only visible in the init() function, so you cannot access it outside of that function.

A solution is to declare it global, that is add to the line

```
var map, layer
```

so this reads

```
var map, layer, layer_1; // and layer_2,...
```

and then use the global variable in the init function (that is, edit `var layer_1 = ...` to read `layer_1 = ...`).